# Getting Started with Ruby on Heroku -- bundle install, puma 2.9.1

Tags: ruby, heroku, installation, bundle, puma

I am trying to install a Ruby bundle on Heroku. I have been following the procedures in the Getting Started with Ruby on Heroku page. When I do `bundle install`, I receive an error, prompting me to install puma v 2.9.1.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

        c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating puma_http11-i386-mingw32.def
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl: In function 'puma_parser_execute':
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl:111:3: warning: comparison between signed and unsign
ed integer expressions
compiling io_buffer.c
io_buffer.c: In function 'buf_to_str':
io_buffer.c:119:3: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'rb_str_new
' differ in signedness
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:661:7: note: expect
ed 'const char *' but argument is of type 'uint8_t *'
compiling mini_ssl.c
In file included from mini_ssl.c:3:0:
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warni
ng: #warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
mini_ssl.c:4:25: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/puma-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.9.
1/ext/puma_http11/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing puma (2.9.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '2.9.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try to install puma, I get this:

```
$ gem install puma -v '2.9.1'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating puma_http11-i386-mingw32.def
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl: In function 'puma_parser_execute':
ext/http11/http11_parser.rl:111:3: warning: comparison between signed and unsign
ed integer expressions
compiling io_buffer.c
io_buffer.c: In function 'buf_to_str':
io_buffer.c:119:3: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'rb_str_new
' differ in signedness
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:661:7: note: expect
ed 'const char *' but argument is of type 'uint8_t *'
compiling mini_ssl.c
In file included from mini_ssl.c:3:0:
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warni
ng: #warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
mini_ssl.c:4:25: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/puma-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/puma-2.9.
1/ext/puma_http11/gem_make.out
```

Can anyone make anything of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue as well!

Here is how I fixed it: I googled 'puma 2.9.1'

the second result suggested specifying the version number in the gem install command like so: gem install --version 2.9.1

it worked!

Answer (score 0):

1. install DevKit, e.g. in c:\devkit
2. unpack the OpenSSL Package, e.g. in c:\openssl (use 7Zip or PeaZip)
3. You need to copy the ddls from the bin directory (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) to your ruby/bin directory.
4. open a windows console
5. initialize the DevKit build environment

   c:\devkit\devkitvars.bat
6. Now it’s possible to install the puma gem with the OpenSSL packages
   gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl

reference: https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows
and: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/202

Answer (score 0):

The key for me was to first grant admin access to brew followed by linking postgresul to brew using the following commands in the order they're listed..

1. sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
2. brew update
3. brew doctor
4. brew link postgresql

After entering this string of commands, everything worked with heroku.

Worth nothing I found a much easier to follow tutorial than heroku here - http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

A lot of the steps herkou puts you through are not central to setting up rails. Thus, unless you're dead set on heroku, you should check out that link.